# Why are my buttons not changing color when selected?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, storyboard

I have several buttons on a single view controller which I want to change color when they are selected. My current code is as follows

```
@IBAction func academicButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if academicButton.backgroundColor == UIColor.systemBackground {
        academicButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20, green: 215, blue: 201, alpha: 1)
        academicButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.systemBackground, for: .selected)
    } else {
        academicButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        academicButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 20, green: 115, blue: 201, alpha: 1), for: .selected)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? (This is just on of the many buttons; they will all do the same thing when selected).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing the color comparison wrong.

Try this;

```
academicButton.backgroundColor.isEqual(UIColor.systemBackground)
```